# Registering plugin's Gutenberg blocks in custom theme

Tags: block-editor

I have a custom theme (developer no longer available). The theme uses Gutenberg. They way it's built is the Gutenberg put in a separate directory inside the theme.
Now I have a plugin "Photo Gallery – GT3 Image Gallery & Gutenberg Block Gallery". It is supposed to be shown in Gutenberg blocks, but because of the theme it's not showing.

The solution I found was to register in theme's functions.php the block. I am trying to do so with different variations of:

```
function register_gt3_custom_blocks() {
    register_block_type( 
        'gt3-photo-video-gallery/dist', // Replace with the actual block name
        array(
            'editor_script' => '/js/gutenberg/editor.js', // Replace with the script handle used by the plugin
            'editor_style'  => '/css/gutenberg/editor.css',  // Replace with the style handle used by the plugin
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'register_gt3_custom_blocks');
```

But it doesn't seem to add the blocks in Gutenberg. What is it am I doing wrong? Tried askign ChatGPT but no help. Checked other solutions and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: "the Gutenberg put in a separate directory inside the theme" - what exactly do you mean here? They've put a whole extra copy of the Gutenberg plugin in the theme?

Comment: @Rup there's a directory inside the theme's directory "gutenberg/acf-blocks" with some extra blocks used on the site. Somehow these blocks are shown on the page editor, but not from the plugin I'm talking about. When I use any other WP theme it works like a charm

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-register blocks within a theme for them to work. Somewhere in your theme there must be code that only allows certain blocks. Search for the `allowed_block_types` filter - most likely that's the culprit, and if you remove the function running on it, it should allow blocks from whatever plugins you install.

Comment: @WebElaine thank you so much! It worked like a charm!